# how to auto compute my total grades to GEN_AVE?

Tags: mysql

this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `GRADES_Q1` (
`Date_Modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
`LRN` BIGINT(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Last_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`First_Name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`Level` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
`Mother_Tongue` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Filipino` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`English` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Science` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Math` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`AP` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`MAPEH` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Music` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Arts` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`PE` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Health` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`ESP` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`Computer` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`TLE` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`CAT` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`EPP` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`GEN_AVE` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`LRN`)
)COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

this is my query

```
UPDATE GRADES_Q1
SET GEN_AVE = (SELECT sum(COALESCE(Mother_Tongue,0))
      + COALESCE(Filipino,0)
      + COALESCE(English,0)
      + COALESCE(Science,0)
      + COALESCE(Math,0)
      + COALESCE(AP,0)
      + COALESCE(MAPEH,0)
      + COALESCE(ESP,0)
      + COALESCE(Computer,0)
      + COALESCE(TLE,0)
      + COALESCE(CAT,0)
      + COALESCE(EPP,0)
      / (12 - (select sum(case when ENGLISH is null then 1 else 0 end
      + case when Math is null then 1 else 0 end
      + case when ESP is null then 1 else 0 end
      + case when Mother_Tongue is null then 1 else 0 end
      + case when Computer is null then 1 else 0 end
      + case when MAPEH is null then 1 else 0 end
      + case when Science is null then 1 else 0 end
      + case when AP is null then 1 else 0 end
      + case when EPP is null then 1 else 0 end
      + case when TLE is null then 1 else 0 end
      + case when CAT is null then 1 else 0 end
      + case when AP is null then 1 else 0 end)

         as grandtotals)))
```

When I run query, I Want to compute (Total sum of grades)/(16-number of null columns) and set it to GEN_AVE or general average.

For Example, (i want it like this)

`Math Science AP   EPP   TLE   GEN_AVE
99    89     90    99    87     92.8`
(computed as sum of grades / number of non null columns.

My Problem, it gives me strange result to my GEN_AVE but no errors (yey!). 
Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: anyone?' please help?

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps do this in an easier manner like so:

```
UPDATE GRADES_Q1
SET GEN_AVE = 
      ( 
        COALESCE(Mother_Tongue,0))
      + COALESCE(Filipino,0)
      + COALESCE(English,0)
      + COALESCE(Science,0)
      + COALESCE(Math,0)
      + COALESCE(AP,0)
      + COALESCE(MAPEH,0)
      + COALESCE(ESP,0)
      + COALESCE(Computer,0)
      + COALESCE(TLE,0)
      + COALESCE(CAT,0)
      + COALESCE(EPP,0)
      )
      / 
      (
        12 
      - case when ENGLISH is null then 1 else 0 end
      - case when Math is null then 1 else 0 end
      - case when ESP is null then 1 else 0 end
      - case when Mother_Tongue is null then 1 else 0 end
      - case when Computer is null then 1 else 0 end
      - case when MAPEH is null then 1 else 0 end
      - case when Science is null then 1 else 0 end
      - case when AP is null then 1 else 0 end
      - case when EPP is null then 1 else 0 end
      - case when TLE is null then 1 else 0 end
      - case when CAT is null then 1 else 0 end
      - case when AP is null then 1 else 0 end
      )
```